# Check if an Auto-Renewable Subscription is still valid? Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am looking for some template code or links to any documentation that could help me find a way to check is a user is still paying for my services or has cancelled ?
I am using StoreKit

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/choosing_a_receipt_validation_technique) you find Apple's documentation on this topic.
For local receipt validation I can recommend [TPInAppReceipt](https://github.com/tikhop/TPInAppReceipt).